# Error when chosing more than 1 data fileds in pivot table in xlsx file

Tags: ruby, axlsx

Using axlsx gem I am trying to write an excel file and adding a pivot table it.
Whenever I chose more than 1 data fields in Pivot Table, the generated excel file is not opening in MS Excel.

I am getting the following error: 
[image]

Comment: Can you post your actual code the error message is not very useful without the ability to determine why this is occurring. As of right now you have not actually asked a question.